# Is anything wrong with this linq insert? Seems like a lot of SQL for simple operation

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm pretty new to the MVC / c# / Linq way of doing things.

It seems ***really*** inefficient.  Am I doing something incorrectly or am I mistaken in any assumptions?

For example, adding a new post to a forum thread might look something like this:

```
    public ActionResult AddNewPost(int userID, int threadID, string content)
    {
        User user = DataContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == userID);
        Thread thread = DataContext.Threads.Include(t => t.Posts).FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == threadID);
        Post post = new Post()
        {   
            Content = content,
            User = user
        }
        thread.Posts.Add(post);
        DataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Now, behind the scenes, this generates a lot of sql to:

- select all the thread details
- plus all the posts in that thread (there could be quite a lot)
- it also selects all the user's details

That's quite a lot of selecting, even before even performing the INSERT operation. To update the Posts table we only really need the threadID and userID  which are passed in as parameters anyway. As a contrast, the same operation in classic asp or php would require no selects, and a relatively simple insert like this:

`INSERT into forum_posts (threadID, postID, content) VALUES (threadID, postID, 'content')`

Am I doing something incorrectly with the MVC example above?

***Update***

Thanks for your comments, much appreciated. My current model is like this:

```
    public class Post
    {
        User User {get;set;}
        Thread Thread {get;set;}
        string Content {get;set;}
    }
```

And you're recommending I change it to this:

```
    public class Post
    {
        User User {get;set;}
        UserID UserID {get;set;}
        Thread Thread {get;set;}
        ThreadID ThreadID {get;set;}
        string Content {get;set;}
    }
```

Which would allow me to do this:

```
        Post post = new Post()
        {   
            Content = content,
            UserID = userID,
            ThreadID = threadID,
        }
        DataContext.Posts.Add(post);
```

I would like to leave in the User and Thread members so that I can use them for navigation, like so: 
`Post.User.UserName`.

But I can just use the ID properties when adding the post to the DB, as above.

Have I understood correctly?

Comment: have you exposed the userId and threadId on the Post class? if so you could skip getting the user and posts and just manually set the UserId and thread id on the post. and then add it to the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should be able to add new post this way

```
    Post post = new Post()
    {   
        Content = content,
        userID = userID,
        threadID = threadID
    }

    DataContext.Posts.Add(post);
    DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

UPDATE: this is what your class should look like if you want to expose the UserID and ThreadID.

```
public class Post
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    UserID UserID {get;set;}
    User User {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("Thread")]
    ThreadID ThreadID {get;set;}
    Thread Thread {get;set;}

    string Content {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: add directly to the posts table

Comment: Ok, cool, thanks.  I updated the question just to clarify I've understood you correctly. It wouldn't really fit into a comment.

Comment: i've updated the answer to include the foreign key mapping so it will map the keys to your User and Thread models.